# Malformed Manifest - Cannot find the declaration of element manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

When launching the application a Failures manifest malformed error occurs what is the problem in my manifest file?

I've been looking around and i've already checked for:

1. I've checked for capitalization
2. The packages are set properly
3. All the libraries for Parse and facebook has been imported properly.
   (or maybe i missed out on something)

I've also tried commenting out parts to see if it would compile though with no avail.

I've also ran a validate and these errors were shown

```
Error:(1, 56) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'null', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
Error:(3, 38) cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'manifest'.
Error:(1, 56) s4s-elt-schema-ns: The namespace of element 'x' must be from the schema namespace, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.
Error:(1, 56) s4s-elt-invalid: Element 'x' is not a valid element in a schema document.
```

I don't understand those error and what Element X is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="artisedesolution.task" >


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!-- PARSE -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" />
<supports-screens android:normalScreens="true" />

<permission
    android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- PARSE -->
<application
    android:name="Utilities.AppUtilities"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/appicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
    <activity  android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"       android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.RegistrationTemplate"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_registration"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Activities.Login" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Task"
        android:label="Task"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.SignUp"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Activities.Login" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.ClaimCode"
        android:label="Pocket"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Activities.Task" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Join"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_join"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Activities.Task" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.TaskInstantGratification"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_task_instant_gratification"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.TaskRate"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_task_rate"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.TaskPhoto"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_task_photo"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.TaskSurprise"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_task_surprise"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.TaskSurvey"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_task_survey"
        android:parentActivityName=".Activities.Join"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Activities.Join" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Edit"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edit"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Activities.Join" />
    </activity>


    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
         <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="artisedesolution.task" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.About"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_about"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Activities.Task" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.InstructionsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_instructions" >
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

put your xml manifest in http://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidate
there is space in line 43

Comment: Hi thank you for replying, line 43 was just a mis format. I've copied my manifest on xmlvalidate and there was no error that occurred. @visionix

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
    <activity               android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
```

should be

```
<activity     
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
```

EDIT :

Did you extends AppUtilities in AppUtilities ? Because the java class referenced in

```
<application 
    android:name=".Utilities.AppUtilities" 
     ..... >
```

is a class that extends android.app.Application

Comment: Oh sorry the line of code is really long so when inputing it in stackoverflow it did not format well. @koni

Answer (score 0):

`<application
    android:name="Utilities.AppUtilities"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/appicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >`

On  `android:name="Utilities.AppUtilities"` you miss a point i think: `android:name=".Utilities.AppUtilities"` or you can do `android:name="Utilities_AppUtilities"`

Comment: Hi thank you for trying but sorry it did not solve the issue. @Braindead

Comment: I specified SDK version and later the solution i gived after and it works for me

Comment: Hey! Malformed Manifest didn't show up anymore. Though the name is highlighted Red now maybe the path i specified is not correct for the name. I'll look into it first thanks again.

Comment: May i ask how do i get the android:name under application because it seems that i'm giving the wrong one. Or maybe there is a configuration that i need to change for Utilities.AppUtlities to work. @Braindead

Comment: The android:name=".Utilities.AppUtilities" is a java class that extends android.app.Application